# updating a table using ajax doesn't work when dealing with more than one record

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I'm working on a groovy grails application for a performance review tool. i'm currently making a form that creates a table which lists the supervisor(s) for an employee. This table has a delete button for each record in the first column. When clicked, the form will post to the `delete` action (which works fine). I'm trying to use `jquery` to make an `ajax call` to make the entire process happen without refreshing the page. If there is only one supervisor, the ajax call works fine but if there is more than one supervisor, the ajax call fails even though the delete happened.

list.gsp

```
<div class="form-action">
    <div id="deleteSupervisorReport">
        <g:render template="displaySupervisorsTemplate" model="[supervisorReportInstanceList: supervisorReportInstanceList]"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

_displaySupervisorsTemplate.gsp

```
<g:if test="${supervisorReportInstanceList.size() > 0}">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-dataTable">
    <caption class="hide">Supervisor Reports</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Employee Type</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each var="supervisorReport" in="${supervisorReportInstanceList}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <g:form  action="delete" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                    <g:hiddenField name="reportId" value="${supervisorReport.reportId}"/>
                    <g:hiddenField name="supervisorId" value="${supervisorReport.supervisorId}"/>
                    <g:actionSubmit class="delete"  value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'delete')}" />
                </g:form>
            </td>
            <td><pr:personLink person="${supervisorReport.supervisor}" /></td>
            <td>${fieldValue(bean: supervisorReport.supervisor, field: "employeeType")}</td>
            <td>${fieldValue(bean: supervisorReport.supervisor, field: "currentTitle.startDate")}</td>
            <td>${fieldValue(bean: supervisorReport.supervisor, field: "currentTitle.name")}</td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <p>You have no Reports.</p>
</g:else>
```

main.js

```
// Attach the delete supervisor submission handler
$("body").on("submit", "#deleteSupervisorReport form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var method = this.method;
    var action = this.action;
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: action,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            // Replace the table
            $("#deleteSupervisorReport").replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            // this alert pops up whenever I try to delete a record when a person has more than one supervisor
            alert("javascript Error, please refresh the page");
        }
    });
});
```

delete action

```
// Delete a specific SupervisorReport
def delete() {
    withSupervisorReport { supervisorReportInstance ->            
        supervisorReportInstance.delete(flush: true)
        withFormat {
            html {
                def list = SupervisorReport.findAllByReport(Person.get(params.reportId as Integer))
                def message = 'Supervisor report deleted'
                def messageType = "Success"

                render(template:"/supervisorReport/displaySupervisorsTemplate", model: [supervisorReportInstanceList: list, message: message, messageType: messageType])
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Sorry for the plethora of code but I don't even know where the problem is.

Comment: Can you change your error handler to something like `function     (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    console.log(exception.message);
                    console.log(exception.number || exception.lineNumber);

                }` to get a better idea of what the error is?

Comment: coming back as undefined.

Comment: Have you used Firebug or your browser's developer tools to capture the response to see if it looks okay?

Comment: I've actually narrowed down the problem quite a bit. I will need to post another question because my problem occurs when I render my template. Thanks a lot for the help :)